# Sbt test throws IncompatibleClassChangeError when using Scalaz

Tags: scala, sbt, scalaz

Sbt test throws

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scalaz.Memo, but interface was expected`

when scalaz is a dependency.

`sbt dependency-graph`:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ixaxaar/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/project
[info] Set current project to cerebro (in build file:/Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/}cerebro...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] default:cerebro_2.10:1.0 [S]
[info]   +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
[info]   | +-ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |
[info]   +-com.github.tototoshi:scala-csv_2.10:1.2.1 [S]
[info]   +-com.h2database:h2:1.4.187
[info]   +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.6 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 (evicted by: 1.3.0)
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   |
[info]   +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   +-com.typesafe:scalalogging-slf4j_2.10:1.1.0
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |
[info]   +-edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.5.2
[info]   | +-com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.23
[info]   | +-com.io7m.xom:xom:1.2.10
[info]   | | +-xalan:xalan:2.7.0
[info]   | | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
[info]   | | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2 (evicted by: 1.3.03)
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-de.jollyday:jollyday:0.4.7
[info]   | | +-javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.1 (evicted by: 2.8)
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-javax.json:javax.json-api:1.0
[info]   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.1 (evicted by: 2.8)
[info]   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   |
[info]   +-edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-parser:3.5.2
[info]   | +-com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.23
[info]   |
[info]   +-io.spray:spray-can_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-io_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   |
[info]   +-io.spray:spray-routing_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | +-com.chuusai:shapeless_2.10:1.2.4 [S]
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-httpx_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:1.9.4
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   |
[info]   +-mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.2.1
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.2
[info]   +-org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:3.2.4 [S]
[info]   | +-org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:3.2.4 [S]
[info]   |   +-com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.5.2
[info]   |   +-org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:3.2.4 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.scala-lang:scalap:2.10.0
[info]   |     +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.0 [S]
[info]   |       +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.0 [S] (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   |       +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.2.0-M2 [S]
[info]   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-config_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 (evicted by: 1.3.0)
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-interpolation_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   |   | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   |   | |
[info]   |   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   |   | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-interpolation-macro_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   |   +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   |   |   | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   |   |   |
[info]   |   |   +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   |   |   +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   |   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12
[info]     +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]
```

`sbt about`:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ixaxaar/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/project
[info] Set current project to cerebro (in build file:/Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/}cerebro...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] This is sbt 0.13.0
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/}cerebro 1.0
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.4
[info] Available Plugins: net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin, sbtassembly.Plugin, com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.2
```

`sbt test`:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ixaxaar/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/project
[info] Set current project to cerebro (in build file:/Users/ixaxaar/src/cerebro/)
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scalaz.Memo, but interface was expected
    at org.specs2.main.Extract$class.$init$(Arguments.scala:460)
    at org.specs2.main.Arguments$.<init>(Arguments.scala:112)
    at org.specs2.main.Arguments$.<clinit>(Arguments.scala)
    at org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner.<init>(SbtRunner.scala:49)
    at org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework.runner(SbtRunner.scala:25)
    at org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework.runner(SbtRunner.scala:21)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$createTestRunners$1.apply(Defaults.scala:478)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$createTestRunners$1.apply(Defaults.scala:473)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3.foreach(Map.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.Defaults$.createTestRunners(Defaults.scala:473)
    at sbt.Defaults$.allTestGroupsTask(Defaults.scala:484)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$4.apply(Defaults.scala:361)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$testTasks$4.apply(Defaults.scala:361)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:35)
    at scala.Function7$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function7.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (test:executeTests) java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class scalaz.Memo, but interface was expected
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 18 Aug, 2015 4:25:37 PM
```

Edit: `sbt test:dependencyGraph`:

```
[info]   +-ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
[info]   | +-ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |
[info]   +-com.github.tototoshi:scala-csv_2.10:1.2.1 [S]
[info]   +-com.h2database:h2:1.4.187
[info]   +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.6 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 (evicted by: 1.3.0)
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   |
[info]   +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.10:2.3.6 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.6 [S]
[info]   |   +-com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 (evicted by: 1.3.0)
[info]   |   +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   |
[info]   +-com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 (evicted by: 1.3.0)
[info]   +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   +-com.typesafe:scalalogging-slf4j_2.10:1.1.0
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 (evicted by: 1.7.12)
[info]   |
[info]   +-edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.5.2
[info]   | +-com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.23
[info]   | +-com.io7m.xom:xom:1.2.10
[info]   | | +-xalan:xalan:2.7.0
[info]   | | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
[info]   | | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2 (evicted by: 1.3.03)
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-xerces:xercesImpl:2.8.0
[info]   | | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.03
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-de.jollyday:jollyday:0.4.7
[info]   | | +-javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.7
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.1 (evicted by: 2.8)
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-javax.json:javax.json-api:1.0
[info]   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.1 (evicted by: 2.8)
[info]   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   |
[info]   +-edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-parser:3.5.2
[info]   | +-com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.23
[info]   |
[info]   +-io.spray:spray-can_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-io_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   |
[info]   +-io.spray:spray-routing_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | +-com.chuusai:shapeless_2.10:1.2.4 [S]
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-httpx_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-http_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.6 [S]
[info]   | | |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:1.9.4
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   |
[info]   +-io.spray:spray-testkit_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.10:2.3.6 [S]
[info]   | | +-com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.3.6 [S]
[info]   | |   +-com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 (evicted by: 1.3.0)
[info]   | |   +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-io.spray:spray-util_2.10:1.3.2 [S]
[info]   | +-org.specs2:specs2_2.10:2.3.10 [S]
[info]   |   +-junit:junit:4.11
[info]   |   | +-org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
[info]   |   +-org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5
[info]   |   | +-org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1 (evicted by: 1.3)
[info]   |   | +-org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
[info]   |   | +-org.objenesis:objenesis:1.0
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.pegdown:pegdown:1.2.1
[info]   |   | +-org.parboiled:parboiled-java:1.1.4
[info]   |   |   +-org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:4.1
[info]   |   |   | +-org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:4.1
[info]   |   |   |   +-org.ow2.asm:asm:4.1
[info]   |   |   |
[info]   |   |   +-org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:4.1
[info]   |   |   | +-org.ow2.asm:asm:4.1
[info]   |   |   |
[info]   |   |   +-org.ow2.asm:asm-util:4.1
[info]   |   |   | +-org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:4.1
[info]   |   |   |   +-org.ow2.asm:asm:4.1
[info]   |   |   |
[info]   |   |   +-org.ow2.asm:asm:4.1
[info]   |   |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.4 (evicted by: 1.1.6)
[info]   |   |   +-org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.6
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.3 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.scalacheck:scalacheck_2.10:1.11.3 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-sbt:test-interface:1.0
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.scalamacros:quasiquotes_2.10.3:2.0.0-M3 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-concurrent_2.10:7.0.6 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.0.6 (evicted by: 7.2.0-M2)
[info]   |   | +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.2.0-M2 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scalaz:scalaz-effect_2.10:7.0.6 [S]
[info]   |   |   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.0.6 (evicted by: 7.2.0-M2)
[info]   |   |   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.2.0-M2 [S]
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.0.6 (evicted by: 7.2.0-M2)
[info]   |   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.2.0-M2 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.specs2:classycle:1.4.3
[info]   |
[info]   +-mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-codecs:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:5.2.1
[info]   | | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:5.2.1
[info]   | +-org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:5.2.1
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.2
[info]   +-org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:3.2.4 [S]
[info]   | +-org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:3.2.4 [S]
[info]   |   +-com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.5.2
[info]   |   +-org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:3.2.4 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.scala-lang:scalap:2.10.0
[info]   |     +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.0 [S] (evicted by: 2.10.3)
[info]   |     | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.0 [S] (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   |     | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |     |
[info]   |     +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.3 [S]
[info]   |       +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   |       +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.scalatest:scalatest_2.10:2.1.4 [S]
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.3 (evicted by: 2.10.5)
[info]   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.0.6 (evicted by: 7.2.0-M2)
[info]   +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.10:7.2.0-M2 [S]
[info]   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-config_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.2.1 (evicted by: 1.3.0)
[info]   | +-com.typesafe:config:1.3.0
[info]   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-test_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | | | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   | | | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   | | | |
[info]   | | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   | | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-interpolation_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | |   | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   | |   | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   | |   | |
[info]   | |   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | |   | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   | |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |   |
[info]   | |   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-interpolation-macro_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   | |   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | |   |   +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   | |   |   | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   | |   |   |
[info]   | |   |   +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | |   |   +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   | |   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |   |
[info]   | |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   | | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   | | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   | | |
[info]   | | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   | | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   | | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   | |
[info]   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-interpolation_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   | +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   |   | | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   |   | |
[info]   |   | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   |   | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   |   | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-interpolation-macro_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.5 [S]
[info]   |   | +-org.scalikejdbc:scalikejdbc-core_2.10:2.2.7 [S]
[info]   |   |   +-commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
[info]   |   |   | +-commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
[info]   |   |   |
[info]   |   |   +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8
[info]   |   |   +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.7
[info]   |   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |   |
[info]   |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
[info]   |
[info]   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12
[info]     +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when code is compiled with one version of scalaz and run against a different, incompatible version.

Memo did indeed change from a [trait in 7.1](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.1.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Memo.scala) to a [abstract class in 7.2](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Memo.scala). Because this is happening during tests, you should be checking `sbt test:dependencyGraph` not `sbt dependencyGraph`. I am guessing that if you run this you will find that specs2 has a dependency on scalaz 7.1 which is incompatible with your dependency on scalaz 7.2

Comment: Spot-on, Thanks! There was a dependency on scalaz `7.0.6`.

Comment: What is the way around this problem? I have same issue, and it can't be fixed by updating version of specs2, because even the latest depends on scalaz 7.1.6, and I need the scalaz 7.2.0...

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Use the new specs2 version `3.7` which fixes the issue.

For older versions of specs2:

Adding a resolution to the explanation of stew:

The maintainer of specs2 intends to fix this issue with the next release. In the meantime, you may change your specs2 version to the following:
`3.6.6-scalaz-7.2.0`

This was suggested in the issue tracker of specs2: https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/444